# How to disable lock screen on idle for windows 10 host and windows 10 client remote desktop?

Tags: rdp, windows-10

The windows 10 desktop client for *remote desktop* can save my password for the remote client ( a windows 10 VM ). This is all good. Just click to open a session. However after a 5 minute timeout the remote desktop locks the screen and asks for the password. I then disconnect the RDP session and click on the saved RDP session and I am back in. No password needed but this is annoying.

I have tried changing the timeout on the remote windows 10 system but I seem to be locked out of doing that.

[image]

Notice that the option to change the timeout is greyed out. Is there a way to *ungrey* this option or is there another way to achieve this?

*(I originally found [this](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/disable-remote-desktop-auto-lock-screen-on-idle/) but as you see above it doesn't work )*

Comment: Set the screensaver to None?

Answer (score 4):

As described in the article [Disable Remote Desktop Auto Lock Screen on Idle](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/disable-remote-desktop-auto-lock-screen-on-idle/) you have already found:

> If the “On Resume, display logon screen” checkbox is disabled or
>   grayed out like what is shown at the screenshot below, it means that
>   there is a group policy being implemented probably by your company’s
>   network administrator to prevent the local logged in user from
>   changing this setting.

After that the article is bullshit; you should not fight with Group Policy by using some local registry tweaks!

The [Screen Saver Group Policy Settings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938799.aspx) are in:

User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Control Panel\Display

Currently *Password protect the screen saver* is *enabled*. Change to *disabled* to get directly what you want or *not configured* for letting your users deside.

(If you can't change the GPO, your question becomes off-topic on Serverfault.)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I've found to deal with this is to run a mouse mover/jiggler program that periodically moves the mouse a few pixels every minute or so in order to simulate mouse activity.